# HTML Element that Allows Pasting of Images on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, image, paste

I made a simple site that allows users to paste images and text on a site and have it save serverside. It all works on desktop, and using an input field I was able to get text pasting to work on mobile.

```
<input type="text" onpaste="paste(event)">
```

Trouble is, IOS disables the "paste" option in a text field if the clipboard contains an image.

I already know how to handle the image paste, I just need some kind of HTML element that will allow mobile clients to fire the paste event with an image on their clipboard. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?